# Prove there exists a polynomial of degree $2m - 1$ satisfying $f(x_j) = c_j$ and $f'(x_j) = d_j$ for $j = 1, ... , m$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a polynomial of degree $2m - 1$ satisfying $f(x_j) = c_j$ and $f'(x_j) = d_j$ for $j = 1, ... , m$.

My first idea was to start with $n=1$. In this case, define $p(x) = c_1 + d_1(x-x_1)$. I cant seem to generalize this to the second case. I am thinking that there must be a way to prove the existence without explicitly defining a polynomial.

One possibility is to use Lagrange Interpolation. Perhaps we can use an inductive argument on the system of equations we produce.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** By Lagrange Interpolation, you can find a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $m-1$ such that $P(x_j) = c_j$.

Then, your $f(x)$ must have the form
$$f(x)=P(X)+Q(X) \prod (x-c_i)$$
with $\deg(Q)=m-1$.

Now, $f'(x_j) = d_j$ becomes
$$Q(x_j) =\frac{d_j-P'(x_j)}{\prod_{j \neq i} (c_j-c_i)}$$ 
thus, you can find $Q$ via Lagrange Interpolation.